# How do I prevent desktop Icons from changing suddenly

Tags: desktop-icons

Strangely, every time I boot up my computer the desktop icons seem to be in a new random location. this has never happened in the past and only suddenly started a few days ago. Nothing I try to prevent it seems to work and the internet is no help.

I'm updated to the latest version of Ubuntu if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: please [edit] your question with details of which version of ubuntu you are using, which desktop environment and perhaps an image of the desktop issue you are experiencing. As your question currently stands, it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. It was apparently a bug with Steam that caused the script that saves the locations of desktop icons to change the value to a random position every few hours.

That just goes to show that you should update  if there's a problem, because it usually has the solution